# Why does a jQuery Ajax request in IE is returning null?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, null

This is how my request is looking right now. If i acces directly the server url it works. It's returning the needed data. In Chrome and Firefox works flawless. In IE it doesn't. The request is successful but the returned json is null. It does the same thing in Firefox 3.0 as in IE.

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://www.tpltm.ro/dbm/index.php?r=routes/get&type=4e60922f2eb58",
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType : "json",
                        success: function(msg) {
                          console.log(msg);
                               createMenu(msg);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                               console.log("Error: ajaxRequest");
                        }
                 });
```

Comment: Are you going cross domains? Then you need to use JSONP. If not, why use full path?

Comment: Try URL encoding that forward-slash in the `r` query parameter, eg `r=routes%2Fget`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the problem isn't simply the 'console.log(msg);' which would cause IE to silently fails before executing the  'createMenu' function ?